# Confusion in fixed point iteration method

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Find a real root of equation $x^3+x^2-1=0$ in the interval [0,1] with an accuracy of $10^{-4}$.

Above is a problem from my mathematics class on numerical analysis.

**Following is what I have tried:**

$x^3+x^2-1=0 \implies x=\frac{1}{x^2+x}$ and using iteration formula $x_{n+1}=\phi(x_n)$ where
$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+x}$

Root is given to belong to [0,1], so as initial approximation I took $x_0=0.5$ and proceeded. But it is do not approach to the any point, it is not hard to see that the iteration is oscillating around 1.

**What was done in class:**

$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$, this worked.

**My confusion:**

The problem is to find a real root of $f(x)=0$,in fixed point iteration method we change $f(x)=0$ to $x=\phi(x)$ and then use the iteration formula $x_{n+1}=\phi(x_n)$.

What I have done in the problem, why that approach failed and why? And is there any criteria for choosing $\phi(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the function you've selected $\color{blue}{\phi'(x)  = -\frac{2x+1}{(x^2+x)^2}}$

and at $x_0 = 0.5$$ \ \phi'(x) = -3.5555\cdots$

But for the application of fixed point iteration method, you need $\color{blue}{|\phi'(x)|<1}$

Clearly the selected function doesn't satisfy the condition.

---

So take, $x^3 +x^2-1=0 \implies \phi(x) =x = (1-x^2)^{1/3}$
$$\phi'(x)=-\frac{2x}{3(1-x^2)^{2/3}}$$

This has a magnitude less than $1$ at the points of consideration.

Answer (score 3):

Or even more simple than looking at the derivative like in the other answer, you want an iteration that maps the interval $[0,1]$ into itself. However, with your map $x\mapsto \frac1{x+x^2}$, points close to $0$ are mapped to very large points far away from the interval. The given map $x\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt{1+x}}$ does not have this problem, it maps the interval into itself.

The fastest (relatively) simple fixed-point iteration for this equation is the Newton method for the "degree-balanced" function $f(x)=x^2+x-x^{-1}$, 
$$
x_{+1}=g(x)=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
=x-\frac{x^2+x-x^{-1}}{2x+1+x^{-2}}
=x\frac{x^3+2}{2x^3+x^2+1}
$$
It give the iteration sequence starting in the middle of the interval

```
 0:  0.50000000000000000
 1:  0.70833333333333337
 2:  0.75407185204559835
 3:  0.75487746388872945
 4:  0.75487766624668007
 5:  0.75487766624669272
 6:  0.75487766624669272
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice trick is to exploit the fact that $T_3(x)=4x^3-3x=\cos(3\arccos x)$, hence in locating the roots of $f(x)=x^3+x^2-1$ it is possible to enforce the substitution $x=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\cosh\theta}$ in order to get
$$ \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8\cosh^3\theta}+\frac{3}{4\cosh^2\theta} = 1, $$
$$ 4\cosh^3\theta - 3\cosh\theta = \cosh(3\theta)= \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2} $$
then
$$ \theta = \frac{1}{3}\operatorname{arccosh}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) =\frac{1}{3}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{27}+\sqrt{23}}{2}\right)$$
and
$$ x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{\sqrt{27}+\sqrt{23}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\sqrt{27}+\sqrt{23}}}}\approx 0.75487766624669276.$$
There is a single real root since the stationary points of $f(x)$ occur at $x=0$ and $x=-\frac{2}{3}$ and both $f(0)$ and $f\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)$ are negative. Such root belongs to $(0,1)$ since $f(0)f(1)<0$. Newton's method with starting point $x_0=1$ produces the following sequence of approximations, decreasing towards the actual zero:
$$ \frac{4}{5},\frac{333}{440},\frac{103913617}{137655540},\frac{137803872517532490480941}{182551264498284560927730},\ldots$$
Better approximations are produced by starting at $x_0=\frac{3}{4}$:
$$ \frac{77}{102},\frac{1289516}{1708245},\frac{12113936460107727037}{16047549161626557960},\ldots$$